# xsl help for html table

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Newbie to xslt. I have a xml file which cannot be changed and looks like the below. id attribute will exist in all elements, but the other variables may or may not exist. Any help to approach representing this in xslt is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
<A>
   <B>
      <att id="1" var1="ABC" var2="DEF" />
      <att id="2" var2="FGD" />
      <att id="3" var1="ABC" var3="KQR" />
   </B>
   <C>
      <att id="5" var1="ABC" var2="DEF" />
      <att id="8" var3="FGD" />
      <att id="9" var1="ABC" var4="KQR" />
   </C>
   <D>
      <att id="11" var1="ABC" var2="DEF" />
      <att id="13" var5="FGD" var6="TRE" />
      <att id="14" var1="ABC" var3="KQR" />
   </D>
</A>
```

I would like to create HTML tables that looks like the below:

```
A (Header)
B (Sub-Header)
--------------------------
|ID | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 |
|1  | ABC  | DEF  |      |
|2  |      | FGD  |      |
|3  | ABC  |      | KQR  |
--------------------------
C (Sub-Header)
---------------------------------
|ID | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | Var4 | 
|5  | ABC  | DEF  |      |
|8  |      |      | FGD  |      |      
|9  | ABC  |      |      | KQR  |
---------------------------------
D (Sub-Header)
----------------------------------------
|ID | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | Var5 | Var6 | 
|11 | ABC  | DEF  |      |      |      |
|13 |      |      |      | FGD  | TRE  |   
|14 | ABC  |      | KQR  |      |      |
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: See if this can get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21744053/3016153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, tricky one... grouping in XSLT 1.0 (as the question was tagged) within a scope and on attribute names.

Something like this seems to work...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="kAttsByGrandparent" match="@*[not(local-name() = 'id')]" use="generate-id(ancestor::*[2])"/>
<xsl:key name="kDistinctAttsByGrandparent" match="@*[not(local-name() = 'id')]" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::*[2]), '||', local-name())"/>

<xsl:key name="distinct" match="att" use="."/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    </h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[att]">
    <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    </h1>
    <xsl:variable name="vGrandparentId" select="generate-id()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vDistinctAttNames" select="key('kAttsByGrandparent', $vGrandparentId)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kDistinctAttsByGrandparent', concat($vGrandparentId, '||', local-name()))[1])]"/>
    <table border="1">
        <!-- header row -->
        <tr>
            <th>
                <xsl:text>ID</xsl:text>
            </th>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vDistinctAttNames">
                <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="att">
            <xsl:with-param name="pDistinctAttNames" select="$vDistinctAttNames"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(local-name() = 'att')]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="att">
    <xsl:param name="pDistinctAttNames"/>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
        </td>
        <xsl:variable name="vThisElement" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$pDistinctAttNames">
            <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
            <td>
                <xsl:variable name="vAttName" select="local-name()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$vThisElement/@*[local-name() = $vAttName]"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you! In my "real xsl" I had to remove

                <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>

as it was mapping the wrong header to values. Thanks again!

Comment: @Snath - you may have caught the code before I edited it... I'd forgot the second <xsl:sort>.

Answer (score 0):

I did go with https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp online and `xsltproc` on cli.

XSLT-File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
  <h1>A</h1>
  <h2>B</h2>
  <table border="1">
<tr><th>id</th><th>var1</th><th>var2</th><th>var3</th></tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="/A/B/att">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@var1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@var2"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@var3"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  <h2>C</h2>
  <table border="1">
<tr><th>id</th><th>var1</th><th>var2</th><th>var3</th><th>var4</th></tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="/A/C/att">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@var1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@var2"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@var3"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@var4"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  <h2>D</h2>
  <table border="1">
<tr><th>id</th><th>var1</th><th>var2</th><th>var3</th><th>var5</th><th>var6</th></tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="/A/D/att">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@var1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@var2"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@var3"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@var5"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@var6"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can call it e.g. `xsltproc template.xslt data.xml`.

Comment: thanks for the response. Actually I wanted to dynamically get the headers and values as there are many elements and new elements can be added to xml at the later time. I am sorry to not have specified this earlier. Thanks again!

Comment: maybe next time ;)